# Communication error between host and docker containers in user defined bridged network

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

asking for help with network setup in docker-compose

my infrastructure is described in docker-compose,
it runs a web site based on the Laravel framework,
network custom bridge.

Problem:

1. I can't go to any of the web pages of the site,
   except for index.php
2. The host machine has an IP address from the subnet of docker containers (earlier when everything worked, it had an IP address issued by a wifi router)
3. When the host machine communicates with the docker container "TCP Reset"
4. "tcp retransmission" error occurs when communicating with containers

I add next files:

- docker-compose
- Dockerfile
  *.env
- TCP/IP packet capture file between host system and containers.

Files in google drive:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qwohtogShwQ2hwauKOLtXDSmx-Qwg-mz?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem **was not in the docker container network**.

The problem was solved by:

- deleting database tables
- generate a new key for Laravel application.
- table migrations
- importing data into tables for the application to work

Command to generate application key
`php artisan key:generate`

Table Migration Command
`php artisan migrate`

*Delete tables manually via PHPSTORM IDE
Imported table data via database dumps*